# Why was being a school teacher something looked down upon in Ancient Greece?

Tags: ancient-history, greece

I'm currently doing research on Epicurus for an article and I came across an passage from Timon (a central student of Pyrrho) where he calls Epicurus "*Grammadidascalides*", as if an epithet, along with "lowest dog among physicists" and "most uneducable of living things". Interestingly this appears to have been thrown at him so much that he banned the use of the word "schoolteacher" at some point after he developed his own following. Epicurus had a lot of epithets thrown his way by Stoics, Cynics and later by Christians, but this one I find kind of curious. Anyone have insight into why being the son of a school teacher would have been seen as something not respectable?

Comment: How do we know that the insults had to do with teaching? It sounds like Pyrrho did not receive the same treatment.

Comment: Sorry, more specifically with Timon, the epithet is "son of a school teacher". One additional fragment of history we have of Epicurus's time as a student to Nausiphanes was that during one experience of abuse under him, Nausiphanes taunted him with "being a school teacher". These seem like quite random things from today's perspective to have survived as pieces of knowledge when so much else of his life and work have disappeared forever.

Comment: Apparently, teachers were servants, sometimes outright slaves, therefore their status was low : https://books.google.rs/books?id=6VvXAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=Why+was+being+a+school+teacher+something+looked+down+upon+in+Ancient+Greece&source=bl&ots=bS1Ln1j6My&sig=ACfU3U3hRIzWCxAlSPsbYXsBU-6M_jQG6A&hl=sr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUntfFvsDnAhWQqIsKHedqDpgQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=Why%20was%20being%20a%20school%20teacher%20something%20looked%20down%20upon%20in%20Ancient%20Greece&f=false